# Does tor and entry or relay node with nyx utility keep in save any logs that can deanonymize users of my node?

Tags: node

Does tor and entry or relay node with nyx utility keep in save any logs  that allow to get information that can deanonymize
the user (for example, any entries (notes, logs) about the ip-addresses of connections to the node, data packets, or any keys, etc.)? If so, where are 
these logs and similar information keep on linux? And is it possible to completely, without the possibility of recovery, delete this data? Interested in ensuring safety
users who will transmit traffic through my entry or relay node.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, unless you are operating your relay with debug logging turned on (not the default, and not a recommended setting), no uniquely-identifiable information is logged by Tor (or Nyx).  Other software, such as IDSes or firewalls, could potentially be capturing information, but that is not something within the remit of Tor itself.

Comment: Thank you, do you know a free firewall and free antivirus, preferably with open source code that does not keep logs and information that I described in my previous message, or another, that can deanonymize users of my node if somebody  will get physical access to my computer?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically - it can *help* in deanonymizing you, but it can't do it just off the shelf. To do so you have to log all the chain members